# How can I make Visual Studio display inline documentation for built-in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, jsdoc

In Visual Studio 2010 and 2012, the JavaScript editor supports displaying inline documentation for JavaScript things such as functions. However, Visual Studio didn't appear to ship with this documentation for JavaScript's own built-in parts.

Here's a specific example of what I want to achieve. If I access a `String`'s `charAt` method, here's what currently happens:

[image: Visual Studio shows the return and parameter types, but it doesn't show documentation.]

For built-in .NET classes, Visual Studio provides documentation. I would like to have the same thing for JavaScript.

Regarding how to do this, I think it could be done by providing a JavaScript file that contains stubs documented using JsDoc or VsDoc. Then I could just tell Visual Studio to use it as a reference for IntelliSense. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any existing work that already did this.

Comment: To clarify, using your example, are you looking for a more verbose description of the charAt function, with more than an argument list? The current javascript intellisense seems to list context sensitive methods and their arguments, as your example shows.

Comment: @GravityWell, yes; that's right. Specifically, I would like function summary documentation and parameter documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2012, you can create a JavaScript file with all your VSDoc documentation and then save it as a reference file.

To configure a reference file:

1. Select `TOOLS > Options` from the main menu bar
2. Navigate to `Text Editor > JavaScript > IntelliSense > References`
3. Select `Implicit (Web)` from the Reference Group drop-down list
4. Locate your file and then click `Add`

Comment: Technically, you're right. But I don't really want to type up my own documentation for JavaScript's built-in functions; I'd prefer to re-use existing work.

Answer (score -1):

In VS12, the magic file you need is `~/Scripts/_reference.js`

Place lines like this, substituting the correct path, of course.

It should pick up the jQuery VSDOC if it is there.

```
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/Frameworks/Kendo/kendo.web.exploded.js"/>
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/Frameworks/jQuery/jquery.1.8.2.js"/>
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/kendoize/kendoize.js" />
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/kendoize/validation.js" />
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what I was asking; the question is about documenting **built-in JavaScript functions and things**. The examples you've given all appear to be for external libraries, which I doubt contain this documentation. Regarding the example in the question, would these files contain documentation for `String.prototype.charAt`?

The information you've provided looks useful and helpful, but I don't think this is the right place for it.